# How to place three entries in one line in the flutter (settings ui)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page where I show my weight. The problem is that now I display the gross weight, packaging, net in the list. And I want to mark them in a line. Here is my code:

```html
          SettingsSection(
            title: 'Weight',
            tiles: [

              SettingsTile(

                leading:  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.weightHanging),
                title: 'Gross',
                subtitle: '490000',
                  subtitleTextStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)
              ),
              SettingsTile(
                leading:  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.weightHanging),
                title: 'Packaging',
                subtitle: '19000',
                  subtitleTextStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)
              ),
              SettingsTile(
                leading:  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.weightHanging),
                title: 'Net',
                subtitle: '30000',
                  subtitleTextStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)
              ),
              SettingsTile(

                  leading:  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.weightHanging),
                  title: 'Gross'+'              '+'Packaging'+'              '+'Net',
                  subtitle: '490000'+'         '+ '19000'+'          '+ '30000',
                  subtitleTextStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

This code shows how I display the weight (first 3 entries). But I want to display it in a line, as in the last version. But the problem is that when the weight changes (the number of symbols), everything starts to move and look wrong. Is it possible to make drinking so that nothing moves ??
My image:
[image]

Comment: you want to display your list same as last line ?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil That's right, I showed the first 3 records (this is what it looks like now). And I want it to be like the last one

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil is it possible to do?

Comment: as per my understanding I have try to below answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
   Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Gross'),
                  subtitle: Text('490000'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Packaging'),
                  subtitle: Text('19000'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Net'),
                  subtitle: Text('30000'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: So I see you are not using my approach, but using another. Everything looks as it should, but there is no record group name. Here you see in the photo This group is called "Weight". I have other meanings on the page. Can also add the name "weight" as in the photo. But I couldn't do it

Comment: I would like to fully reproduce the page that I have now, but with your code. Without using my widgets

Comment: what do you exact want?

Comment: I want you to add the word "weight" in your example (the name of the region where the weight is displayed). As I had before (see in the photo in question)

Comment: is it possible to do?